# php save data in text with fopen without null characters

Tags: php

I am trying to capture all `REQUEST` data and save to text file, using this script :

```
<?php 
$blocked           = array('submit');
$list              = null;
$data              = date("G:i - D.M.Y");
$hostname          = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$IPsrv             = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

foreach($_REQUEST as $field_name => $field_value) {
   if(!in_array($field_name, $blocked))
      $list .= "{$field_name} : {$field_value}\n";
}
$list = rtrim($list, "\n");

$fp = fopen("../data.txt", 'a');
fwrite($fp, "
================================
$list
================================");
fclose($fp); 
?>
```

The code works, but  I have one problem, the `data.txt` file is not saved correctly, I have more `NULL` characters. How can resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

str_replace should be able to replace NULL characters?

```
fwrite($fp, "
================================
" . str_replace("\0", "", $list) . "
================================");
```